# Error while computing probabilities of an array list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

one can assign a probability to each element of an array by simply deviding the value of each element by the sum of all array elements. I am trying to do this with python for a long list of numpy arrays. My Code:

```
def calc_probs(self, array_list):

    for array in array_list:
        buffer=array.astype("float")
        s=sum(buffer)
        for e in np.nditer(buffer, op_flags=["readwrite"]):
            e/=s
        self.probs.append(buffer)
```

This code should be working. In fact it IS working when typing it into the interactive mode of IPython. The results are then just what I want them to be. But if I save the code to a file und run, I always get the following ValueError:

> ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape () doesn't match the broadcast shape (10)

I do not understand why this error occures, especially when running from a file. Could anyone please explain it to me and help to solve the problem? 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: What does the input look like?

Comment: What line are you getting the exception on? Also what are your inputs?

Comment: The input is a list of numpy arrays of the form: `array_list = [ np.array, np.array, np.array, ... ]`. All np arrays are 2d and of the same shape (100x100). The error occures on line 7 `e/=s`

Comment: sorry for that. Now it is named correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sum` is `__builtin__.sum`, which doesn't know how to sum a NumPy array so just returns the array unchanged.  The error is happening because you are trying to divide the singular matrix `e` by the 10x10 matrix `s`.

You want `s = np.sum(buffer)`.

This whole code could be simplified to:

```
self.probs.append(array / np.sum(array))
```

Comment: +1 as ipython in interactive mode (--pylab) imports np.sum as sum, so it works in ipython but doesn't works in a file as the OP mentioned.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Now I understand what is goiung on. :)